# Penalty Shot out

Tags: football, penalty-shot

What is the rule should the Goalkeeper save the penalty, (as in a case I experienced), **the ref blows his whistle** then the ball which went away from goal had some backspin on it and slowly proceeded to make its way into the net while the keeper was celebrating winning the shoot out with his team.  Objections from the opposing Manager resulted in the kick being taken again and this time they scored and we went from winning to losing the shot out.
 Anyone know what should have happened?

Comment: Derek - your answer is in the other question linked above. Now, this isn't just a case of the referee making a mistake - they have misapplied the Laws of the Game. Please have your club formally report this to the league or your local FA, as this is a serious error that should result in the result being changed and the referee receiving coaching.

Comment: Thanks Martin, happened a while back now, Pickfords save last night just reminded me and was curious as what would have happened had the ball reacted in the same way. Maybe should have appealed at the time as they were only 12 year olds. Life lesson I suspose, for the Keeper anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[IFAB Laws of the Game - Law 14 – The Penalty Kick](http://www.theifab.com/laws/the-penalty-kick-2018/chapters/penalty-kick-procedure-2018):

> The penalty kick is completed when the ball stops moving, goes out of play or
>   the referee stops play for any offence.

The referee erred by blowing the whistle before the procedure outlined above was complete. The goal should have stood instead of being retaken.

Comment: This may be true for penalty kicks during the match, but for kicks from the penalty mark (i.e. a shootout as described in the question), [Law 10, Section 3](http://www.theifab.com/laws/determining-the-outcome-of-a-match-2018/chapters/kicks-from-the-penalty-mark-2018) is more applicable. "The kick is completed when the ball stops moving, goes out of play or the referee stops play for any offence; the kicker may not play the ball a second time" Note the extra restriction on the ball being touched a second time by the kicker.